# CNN with keras to predict energy

Tags: python, keras, regression

I am new to machine learning and keras library and I made a CNN code for regression like below.

```
%matplotlib inline
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def initial_spin_state(N):
    state = np.random.choice((0.11111, 0.99999), (N, N))
    return state


def metropolis_algorithm(config, beta):

    N = len(config)

    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):

            a = np.random.randint(0, N)
            b = np.random.randint(0, N)
            s = config[a, b]
            near=config[(a+1)%N,b] + config[a,(b+1)%N] + config[(a-1)%N,b] + config[a,(b-1)%N]

            delta = 2 * s *near
            if delta < 0:
                s *= -1
            elif rand() < np.exp(-delta * beta):
                s *= -1
            config[a, b] = s

    return config

def get_energy(config):
    energy = 0
    N = len(config)
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            S = config[i, j]
            near = config[(i+1)%N, j] + config[i,(j+1)%N] + config[(i-1)%N, j] + config[i,(j-1)%N]
            energy += near*S

    return energy


x_train = []
y_train = []
for i in range(50000):

    config = initial_spin_state(16)
    energy = get_energy(config)

    x_train.append(config)
    y_train.append(energy)

x_train = np.array(x_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)

print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)


x_test = []
y_test = []
for j in range(20000):

    config = initial_spin_state(16)
    energy = get_energy(config)

    x_test.append(config)
    y_test.append(energy)

x_test = np.array(x_test)
y_test = np.array(y_test)

print(x_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape)


x_train = x_train.reshape(50000, 16, 16, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(20000, 16, 16, 1)
print(x_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import Adadelta
from keras.regularizers import l2


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2), input_shape = (16, 16, 1), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))


model.add(Conv2D(16, (2, 2), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation = 'relu'))
#model.add(Dense(1024, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

np.random.seed(0)
model.summary()
model.compile(loss = "mse", metrics = ['accuracy'], optimizer = 'adam')



%%time
hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 200, batch_size = 500,
                validation_data = (x_test, y_test), verbose = 2)


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(hist.history['acc'], '_b', label = "training")
plt.plot(hist.history['val_acc'], 'r:', label = "test")
plt.legend()
plt.grid("on")
plt.show()
```

this code is for image input, and contiuous energy value output.

so if I put a image(ising configuration) to CNN, it should predict a energy for the configuration.

the problem is..

when I train CNN, training loss and validation loss is decreased very slowly.

of course, training accuracy and validation accuracy is incread very slowly.

and, sometimes only training accuracy is increasd, val-accuracy is not increased.

genious guys.. what`s wrong with my code??

teach me plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since you are doing regression problem, I dont think its a good idea to use `acc` as your metric, instead, you might consider using mean absolute error `mae` as your matric.

The loss you are using is `mse` (mean **squared** error), so the value would be pretty large especially when you are not normalising your `y` values. However, after running ~25 epochs of your provided code, the `validation loss` dropped to `290.xx` with `13.xx` of `mae` (And it is **not** converging yet). And I tried to use your model to predict some validation data, it works fine. Maybe you should test your model before you assume there is something went wrong.

Comment: thanks, now I am trying to learn mae metric and other things about regression again. but i want something more fast. so could you show me your modified code? it will be very helpful for my learning. thanks

Comment: @NarberralGamma no problem, actually I just changed the metric to be `mae` which in fact doesn't affect the behaviours of backpropagation / forwardpropagation of the model. It just gives you a better interpretation of how well the model is doing. Anyway, here you go:
`model.compile(loss = "mse", metrics = ['mae'], optimizer = 'adam')`